# How does one install modules/stuff in docker if it requires interactive install?

Tags: docker, installation, interactive, docker-build

I have been facing this problem for a long time now. Whenever I try to install anything on docker during build, that requires interactive install, the build "hangs" at the interaction screen. For example, for a [particular](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/11966/install-gui-in-a-docker-in-an-aws-instance) project, I needed to install `sddm` in docker (Yeah, yeah I know I am stupid). Now, the build simply hangs at the step wherein I am supposed to select my keyboard layout. How do I go about such problems?

PS: Not all installation scripts are shell scripts that can be modified (like `apt install sddm -y`).
PS: `spawn` and `echo` is not always helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was pretty easy actually. The ENV variable was to be set properly

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't completely undestand the problem when I posted my first answer. Here's another possible solution:

- run the base container
- exec into the container with bash `docker exec -it mycontainer bash`
- install needed software interactively
- create image from running container with `docker commit mycontainer mytag`